# One To Many With Convenience Backpointer

Tags: objective-c, one-to-many, parse-platform

I'd like to model a one-to-many relationship between users and checkIns on Parse.com. Additionally, I'd like a user to have a convenience pointer to it's lastCheckin, to avoid having to query checkIns to get a user's most recent checkIn. Using the following code, the user's lastCheckin column is always empty in the Data Browser:

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

PFObject *checkIn = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"CheckIn"];
checkIn[@"forUser"] = currentUser;
checkIn[@"foursquareID"] = selectedVenue[@"id"];
checkIn[@"name"] = selectedVenue[@"name"];

checkIn[@"location"] = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:[selectedVenue[@"location"][@"lat"] doubleValue]
                                              longitude:[selectedVenue[@"location"][@"lng"] doubleValue]];

[checkIn saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    currentUser[@"lastCheckin"] = checkIn;
    [currentUser saveInBackground];
}];
```

Removing the following line causes the User.lastCheckin to correctly point to the desired CheckIn in the Data Browser, but obviously this breaks the one-to-many linkage:

```
checkIn[@"forUser"] = currentUser;
```

Is there some way for me to get both the one-to-may relationship between Users and CheckIns, and a User.lastCheckIn pointer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the `lastCheckin` on the User each time you create a new `CheckIn` you can access that checkin easily by fetching the current user and including `lastCheckin` with `includeKey`.

http://blog.parse.com/2011/12/06/queries-for-relational-data/

To get all checkins for a user you can simply query the `CheckIn` class where the current user is equal to `forUser`. That is your 1 to many relationship. You do not need to maintain a relation of checkins on the User class since you have a pointer from each CheckIn instance back to the user as a pointer. When you set `lastCheckin` on the user instance you are not changing the property on older checkins.

Perhaps you are thinking this is like SQL with primary and foreign keys. I get confused by NoSQL since I have a SQL background. I am always learning to think like Parse and NoSQL. What I see above is all you need to query all checkins for a user and the last checkin for a user. You can also simply query all checkins for a user, limit result to 1 and sort it so the newest checkin is the first result. It should be quite fast on Parse.

You may also want to look into using Cloud Code. You could call a Cloud Code function and simply pass the parameters you need to create a new checkin and have all of this work done in Cloud Code. An After Save function could be used to update `lastCheckin` on the user.

http://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Cloud.AfterSaveRequest.html

If you user on Cloud Code you can update how the data is managed without updating the iOS app.

Comment: While what you describe should work, my question is about why it doesn't actually work that way. If both checkIn.forUser and user.lastCheckin are enabled in the code above, only checkIn.forUser has a value. I understand how to query CheckIns for the most recent checkIn for a given user, the idea of user.lastCheckIn is to avoid making that query. Do you have some insight as to why user.lastCheckIn is empty when checkIn.forUser is set? Thanks.